# How to plot the result of Grad function?

Tags: plotting

When I calculate the gradient of a two dimension function like
$r=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ with the syntax of

```
h[x_,y_]:=Grad[1/r,{x,y}]
```

and when I checked the result with

```
h[x,y][[1]]
h[x,y][[2]]
```

I got a right result of $-\frac{x}{(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})^{-3/2}}$ and $-\frac{y}{(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})^{-3/2}}$, respectively.

However, when I tried to plot the function with syntax of

```
VectorPlot[{h[x,y][[1]],h[x,y][[2]]},{x,0.1,0.3},{y,-0.3,0.3}]
```

I found the value in y direction is 0, and I also confirmed with

```
Plot3D[h[x,y][[1]],{x,-0.3,0.3},{y,-0.3,0.3}]
Plot3D[h[x,y][[2]],{x,-0.3,0.3},{y,-0.3,0.3}]
```

and the results are that the first one has a proper plot while the second one shows the function value is 0.

Would anyone give me some clue that how this happened?
Thank you and best regards!

Comment: a typo: `Grad[1/r,{x,y}]` should be `Grad[r,{x,y}]`?

Comment: try `VectorPlot[Evaluate@{h[x,y][[1]],h[x,y][[2]]},{x,0.1,0.3},{y,-0.3,0.3}]` ( better yet as in Ulrich's answer `VectorPlot[h[x,y] ,{x,0.1,0.3},{y,-0.3,0.3}]`) and `Plot3D[Evaluate@h[x,y][[1]],{x,-0.3,0.3},{y,-0.3,0.3}]`, 
`Plot3D[Evaluate@h[x,y][[2]],{x,-0.3,0.3},{y,-0.3,0.3}]`

Comment: Thank you for you reply, yes, it is a typo.

Comment: With the `VectorPlot[Evaluate@{h[x,y][[1]],h[x,y][[2]]},{x,0.1,0.3},{y,-0.3,0.3}]`, it worked, Thank you kglr!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ClearAll[h]
r = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
h[u_, v_] := Evaluate[Grad[1 / r, {x, y}]] /. {x -> u, y -> v}
```

Use [`Evaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) on the first arguments of `VectorPlot` and `Plot3D`:

```
VectorPlot[Evaluate @ h[x, y], {x, .1, 0.3},{y, -0.3, 0.3}]
```

[image]

```
Row[{Plot3D[Evaluate@h[x, y][[1]], {x, -0.3, 0.3}, {y, -0.3, 0.3}], 
  Plot3D[Evaluate@h[x, y][[2]], {x, -0.3, 0.3}, {y, -0.3, 0.3}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: This helped a lot, Thank you! Another question is if I use 'If' expression, it doesn't work again. The function like `h[x_, y_]:= If[-0.01<x<0.01&&-0.01<y<0.01, {0,0}, Grad[1/r,{x,y}]]`, does the `Evaluate` function not work in this situation? Thank you!

Comment: @Amon, try `ClearAll[h];
r=Sqrt[x^2+y^2];h[u_, v_]:= If[-0.01<u<0.01&&-0.01<v<0.01,{0,0},Evaluate[ Grad[1/r,{x,y}]/. {x->u,y->v}]] ; VectorPlot[Evaluate@h[x,y],{x,.1,0.3},{y,-0.3,0.3}]`

Comment: It worked! Thank you@kglr! I'm new to Mathematica, it needs time to learn.

Answer (score 2):

```
h[x_, y_] := Grad[1/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {x, y}]
VectorPlot[h[x, y]//Evaluate, {x, 0.1, 0.3}, {y, -0.3, 0.3}]
```

[image]

Comment: fyi, the above gives blank plot in V 13.2 !  from clean kernel. Screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0vIz.png)  do you think I should post a question on this, or do you something I am not seeing?  But adding `Evaluate` makes it work. ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZX3OQ.png)  Strange that it worked for you without Evaluate. something seems to have changed in 13.2

Comment: @Nasser Thank you for your hint. In the year 2019 it seems to work on MMA version v12. I can't reproduce this result with MMA v12.2. I modified my answer!